# Set onClickListener for custom view

Tags: android

I have created a custom view called Cell that draws a square. In my activity I create a 2d array of cells, hence giving a grid structure. Now the reason for this is, I want individual cells to respond to my clicks based on some value that they have. Say for eg, each cell has a boolean, and based on true of false I will color the cell.I tried doing this with one cell first. But the strange part is, the click event is triggered even when I click outside the cell.
More Information : I  am creating all view in the onCreate method of the activity. 
Let me know if you need more information.

Thanks in advance for your help !
Thought I will edit my original question for other references :) .

```
Activity  

onCreate() {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
LinearLayout masterLayout = new LinearLayout(this);
LinearLayout.LayoutParams params;
params =  new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,     
LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
masterLayout.setLayoutParams(params);
addCells();
setContentView(masterLayout);
}

function addCells() {
for(int i =0; i<2;i++) {
Cell cell = new Cell(this,i);
LinearLayout.LayoutParams viewParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
cell.setLayoutParams(viewParams);
masterLayout.addView(cell);

cell.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
//Do Something here

}
});}}

Custom View :

Cell extends View {
boolean flag=false;
int cellNumber;
float xCoordinate=50;
float yCoordinate=50;

Cell(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
super(context, attrs);
}
Cell (Context context, int i) {
super(context);
cellNumber = i;
}

onDraw(Canvas c) {
paint.setColor(Color.RED);
paint.setStrokeWidth(3);
paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
xCoordinate = xCoordinate + 40*cellNumber;
c.drawRect(xCoordinate,yCoordinate,xCoordinate+40,yCoordinate+40, paint);

}}
```

This is a much simpler version that I was trying out. Now the strange part is, though I am adding two different instances of my custom view, the onDraw() is called just once (on exiting the onCreate() of the activity). From what I read, the onDraw() is called for every new view render. Please enlighten me on that front !

Thanks a lot!

Comment: some code would really be helpful...

Comment: Post your code so that all can help you.. by what you created the squre depends on that you need to set onclicklistener..

Comment: You want to call `invalidate()` at the end of your onDraw function in the customview to let it repeat the drawing process

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you are not setting the onClickListener to the proper layout. Its some how being set to the parent of the element you want. Please share your code for us to zero in on the exact problem.

Answer (score 0):

> the click event is triggered even when I click outside the cell.

Probably you somehow forward the touch events to your cell, at least it is receiving them. In the onTouchEvent() method of your view is decided whether it is a click (and fire the click listener) or long click or drag, etc.

However, please post some code if this didn't help you identify the problem.

Comment: Or as someone else suggested you are setting the listener on the container of the view :)